# What's the easiest way to share a good hero build?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've developed a few good loadouts for my Witch Doctor, and I'd like to somehow show them off.  I think perhaps I could help other players, or perhaps learn of new ways to exploit my abilities to the fullest.

How can I go about getting a succinct, shareable version of my hero's build, including my gear and chosen skills?

I've considered taking a few screenshots and trying to composite them, but perhaps there's some easier view or tool I could use to capture my character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lucky You! Blizzard has created a [Handy Dandy Skill Calculator](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/barbarian) where you can plug in your skills and show it off to the world!

For example, [this is the build I'm currently using for my Demon Hunter](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/calculator/demon-hunter#WeXdfT!bX!aaZZaZ)

Comment: Hey that's not a bad build. Except your passive skills suck. But thanks for the link. +1

Comment: @Coomie it's a level 24 build, so yes. Yes they do.

Comment: I'm running a level 30 DH with almost exactly the same skills. The passive skills kind of suck in general but brooding is the best...